# Static IP- Losing connection after making static ip, Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp, static-ip

I have the following configuration as the static IP in my dhcpcd.conf

file

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.63.102.152/8
static routers=192.168.88.2
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.2
```

I got my router IP from

```
ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}'
```

After I restarting PI I cannot connect to the internet and it wont connect to the router

This is my first attempt with PI. what could possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static IP and the rest of your config are on two different networks. You need to change the static IP assigned to your Pi to put it in the 192.168.88.0/24 subnet.

Change this line:

```
static ip_address=10.63.102.152/8
```

to something like:

```
static ip_address=192.168.88.152/24
```

then reboot.